# is it possible to delete all files from photo/video directory on android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an app that has the functionality to upload all video and photo files to an external server, and I would like to offer the user the possibility to empty their photo and video directory...soon there is some easy way to do that?  erasing everything at once

Answer (score 0):

I assume your app already has a way to get access to the path to the directory you want to clear, and a permission to access the storage. Now having the path to the directory you could simply
`File(pathToDirectory).list().forEach{ it.delete() }`
Customize the behavior based on your needs. For example, you could recursively call the function containing the code above to clear a directory and all included subdirectories, or you could leave folders untouched and just delete files. For that, there are fields `isFile` and `isDirectory`